# add photos to iPhone simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, uiimagepickercontroller

I need than on button click opens iPhone's default album and I'll can chose a photo.

I read a lot about this, but still don't works. 
I do the following:

1. ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/

   I'm storing two pictures  IMG_0000.JPG (300 on 300 px) and IMG_0000.THM (75 on 75px)

   In my app I do the following on button click:

```
- (IBAction) btnOpenAlbum
  {
      album = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
      album.delegate = self;  

      album.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

      [self presentModalViewController: album animated:YES];
  }
```

I tried also UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoAlbum and still no photos in album.

AI solved it in such a way:

- Opened iPhone simulator.
- Drag there photos. And it automatically copy it to folder ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.1/Media/DCIM/100APPLE and named them as IMG_0001.PNG IMG_0002.PNG and so on.

After that all works fine, but:
When I tried to copy item directly to that folder, and give them suitable names, iphone didn't recognized them. And also, when I deleted them from that folder and run simulator - photos where on simulator, but in folder they were not.

What it can be? Thanx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AI solved it in such a way:

Opened iPhone simulator. Drag there photos. And it automatically copy it to folder ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.1/Media/DCIM/100APPLE and named them as IMG_0001.PNG IMG_0002.PNG and so on. After that all works fine, but: When I tried to copy item directly to that folder, and give them suitable names, iphone didn't recognized them. And also, when I deleted them from that folder and run simulator - photos where on simulator, but in folder they were not.