# Why am I not able to add photos to the iOS simulator using the advised methods?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I followed the advice on various forums and S.O. and am still unable to view any photos in the simulator. I did what was said in the following: [add photos to iPhone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223848/add-photos-to-iphone-simulator) and that did not work either.

The drag and drop of images still does not show any pictures from my app. I also manually copied the files in the path: ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.1/Media/DCIM/100APPLE

and that did not work either. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its simple.

1. You just open the image in mac window which you want to put in the simulator library.
2. drag the particular image in the iphone simulator. Simulator will open the image in the Safari.
3. Tap on the Safari's screen and wait for some time the action sheet will available with the Save option.
4. Selecting the Save option and your particular that image will be save in the simulator's photo library.

Comment: That is what I did but it still will not pull them up in the photo library.

Comment: It saves them in a temporary folder which is deleted after the simulator quits.

Answer (score 0):

Open some image trough simulators Safari browser and save it to gallery.